# Refer to attribute previously defined in constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I was wondering if there is any way to refer to a previously defined property in a constructor in Kotlin. Something like:

```
data class Order(
    val id: String,
    val transformedId: String
}
```

and then when initiating the class, do:

```
val orderId = getOrderId()
Order(
    id = orderId,
    transformedId = transform(id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a secondary constructor.

```
data class Order(
    val id: String,
    val transformedId: String
) { 
    constructor(id: String): this(id, transform(id))
}
```

If you want this to be the only way to create the class, you can make the primary constructor private:

```
data class Order private constructor(
    val id: String,
    val transformedId: String
) { 
    constructor(id: String): this(id, transform(id))
}
```

Comment: Thinking of it, in the first case (if both constructions should be possible) we could simply use a default value for `transformedId`. In the second case (if we want to enforce `transformedId` to be the actual transformation of `id`), it's unlikely that it's useful to have that transformed id in the generated `equals`/`hashCode`, so maybe it could just be a separate property (not in the constructor).

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the typo `it`->`id`, btw, I hope you don't mind

Comment: Good points. And thanks for the correction.